# ASP.net MVC Routing with Arbitrary # of Leading Segments?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing

So, this is both a technical and a SEO question.

Let's say you are developing an e-commerce site and the client requests that you maintain the category path in the structure of the URL. Example:

```
/electronics/video-games/ps3/nba2k13-p123774
```

How do you set up a route that will work for this and send things to the product controller regardless of the number of segments before the last segment? Example:

```
{arbitrary_cat_routes}/{name}-p{id}
```

Secondly, I understand wanting to get keywords in the URL, but is there a substantial benefit to this? I've heard that content closer to the root of the site receives some SEO preference. Doesn't buring it 3 directories deep wipe out the SEO benefit of having the keywords there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC routing does not support a catchall parameter anywhere in the URL just on the end. You would need to create a custom Route class that implements this functionality. This [blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.ca/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html) summarizes how you would that. To answer your second question, I would avoid having category metadata in the URL, but I'm not super familiar with SEO.